# Find all the non-zero values and get their interval

Tags: python, pandas

```
name company count_2015  count_2016   count_2017 count_2018 count_2019 last_id
joe     abc     3            0           0           1         2         230283
cindy   bcd     2            0           1           0         3         239382
john    cde     4            0           0           1         0          238372
wang    def     1            1           0           0         3          1332
```

I am trying to get the "average year interval" for the non-zero values. For instance, for joe, the non-zero values are 3, 1, 2 in year 2015, 2018, 2019. The first non-zero value and the second non-zero value has a year interval of (2018 - 2015 = 3). The third non-zero value 2 and the second non-zero value 1 has a year interval of (2019 - 2018 = 1). Therefore, the average interval is (3 + 1)/2 = 2.

The returned column should be
col

```
((2018 - 2015) + (2019 - 2018))/2 = 2
((2017 -2015) + (2019 -2017))/2 = 2
((2018 - 2015))/1 = 3
((2016 - 2015) +(2019 - 2016))/2 =2
```

the ultimate col should be

```
2
2
3
2
```

I tried with `numpy.nozero()` but I need to use pandas to solve this? Is there anyway to solve this problem with pandas?